# Dynamically Insert Pagebreak

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, wysiwyg

My team working in a project using asp.net mvc3(c#). Based on the project requirement,we need to implement page break like Microsoft Word. I need to save the pagebreak and the page size may be a4, letter, legal, etc.

Is it possible to control the page size of the content in the ckeditor and insert page breaks shown inside the editor when it crosses a certain height or size, the same way it works in MS Word>

Is there is any alternative solution?

Comment: In which format are you saving your CKEditor content? to my understanding HTML does not support Page Breaks so you have no way unless you are doing some saving in word format, pdf or another format which supports page breaks, have a look at RTF specifications: http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternative solution I found after searching the google for solving pagebreak by using [RichTextBoxSilverlight](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/RichTextBoxSilverlight/)

some of the features

- RichTextBox fully supports paging and printing. You can edit
  documents in either Print Layout or Draft view; much like Microsoft
  Word. Print Layout supports continuous page flow when scrolling and
  even supports facing multiple pages horizontally.
- RichTextBox supports importing and exporting RTF, Html, and plain
  text. Load existing rich text or Html into the C1RichTextBox control,
  edit the document, and then export it back to RTF or Html.
- Edit and format text containing multiple fonts, decorations, colors,
  tables, images, lists, and more.
- RichTextBoxToolbar includes the following commands: Paste, Cut, Copy,
  Undo, Redo, Font Family, Font Size, Grow Font, Shrink Font, Bold,
  Italic, Underline, Change Case, Subscript, Superscript, Text Color,
  Text Highlight Color, Align Left, Align Center, Align Right, Justify,
  Bullets, Numbering, Text Wrapping, Border Thickness, Border Color,
  Paragraph Color, Margin, Padding, Insert Image, Insert Symbol, Insert
  Hyperlink, Remove Hyperlink, Find and Replace, Spell Check, and
  additional commands for inserting/editing Tables.
- RichTextBox for inserting and editing images. Users can easily upload
  images from their computer to the editor or point to an image's url
  on the web. Users can also select, resize and drag images on the document surface.
- RichTextBox supports page zooming in both print layout and draft
  views.
- RichTextBox content can be exported to PDF format.
- Edit data in the RichTextBox with confidence. You now have the
  ability to easily undo and redo your changes with the click of a
  button.

Comment: Microsoft Silverlight will reach the end of support on October 12, 2021. [Silverlight End of Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4511036/silverlight-end-of-support)

Answer (score 7):

Like graphicdivine says, use print CSS to accomplish what you need to do. Create a css class that has a `page-break-before` definition, and dynamically add that class to the first element of the page after the break.

You could also do something like this:

```
br.pageBreak {
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

and then insert a `<br class="pageBreak" />` at the point where you need a page break.

More info:

Page-breaks: http://www.w3.org/TR/css-print/#s.8.2

Page size: http://www.w3.org/TR/css-print/#s.8.3

An old A List Apart article: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

Unfortunately, I do not know if it is possible to alter CKEditor in this way without hassle.

Comment: CKEditor already has a button that inserts <div style="page-break-after: always;"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></div>
 but I doubt that this is what he wants.

Comment: I need to implement page break dynamically not by clicking a button in the editor

Comment: To my knowledge, atornblad's solution is as good as it gets for HTML.  Page breaks are a giant PITA in HTML, but this solution does work.  The question is...  can your user tell you what size they want the page before printing (e.g. A4, etc.) and if so, then you have a workable solution.  If you don't know beforehand, then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using CSS2's `page-break-before` and `page-break-after`, although how and where you dynamically insert them is another matter.